# Remove Extra \ in XML column in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this XML in the SQL table column that the type of the column is TEXT. I would like to Remove Extra \ that is existed is some of the XMLs.

This is the XML:

```
 <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
 <Ist xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"     xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
    <Credit>
<LoanApp>
  <Routing Transaction=\"LoanApp\">
    <Processing>
      <Process Type=\"Trans-type\">pass</Process>
    </Processing>
    <From>
      <IDs>
        <ID Type=\"Network\">WEBSITE</ID>
        <ID Type=\"WEB\">WEBSITE</ID>
        <ID Type=\"D\">4054563</ID>
      </IDs>
```

Comment: to me all of these back slashes needs to go, you can simply do `REPLACE(ColumnName, '\', '')`

Comment: What you're replacing are escaped quotation marks. You should include the quotation in your search string: `XmlColumn = REPLACE(XmlColumn, '\"', '"')`

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ 's method seems the best as the \ is used to escape the double quotes. So it makes more sense to replace `\"` by `"`. Replacing \ by nothing can break your XML if theres any stray \ in your data.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You have tags for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to replace are escaped quotation marks. You should include the quotation in your search string so back-slashes that exist on their own don't get replaced accidentally:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn, '\"', '"')
```

Just as an aside, in some cases, the escaped attribute values might be necessary, and it could be more appropriate to unescape the XML string in the UI layer and leave it as-is in your table.

Lastly, you're storing XML in a column of type `text`, which has been deprecated for a long time. You should also think about switching to the `xml` data type if your version of SQL server allows it.

Comment: I don't need to update I can select it in my store proc. like this:select Cast(REPLACE(Cast(Request as varchar(max)), '\"', '"') as xml)  FROM table